# Responsive canvas extends beyond div

Tags: html, css, twitter-bootstrap-3, chart.js

I am using ChartJS to place a responsive chart within a div. I am also using bootstrap, so the div class is grid focused (ex. md-9). The chart keeps expanding beyond the div. I was considering overflow: hidden on the div but don't want to lose any data from being shown. Here is a link to my development site. Any assistance is appreciated:

http://investingcalculator.azurewebsites.net

My current HTML code:

```
        <div class="budgetcalcsection">
        <div class="row">

            <div class="col-sm-3 col-md-2">

                <div class="inputtext">
                    Current Balance
                    <div class="input-group">
                        <span class="input-group-addon">$</span>
                        <input type="number" id="currentbalance" class="form-control" placeholder="0">
                    </div>
                </div>

                <div class="inputtext">
                    Interest Rate
                    <div class="input-group">
                        <span class="input-group-addon">%</span>
                        <input type="number" id="interestrate" class="form-control" placeholder="0">
                    </div>
                </div>

                <div class="inputtext">
                    Monthly Contributions
                    <div class="input-group">
                        <span class="input-group-addon">$</span>
                        <input type="number" id="monthlycontribution" class="form-control" placeholder="0">
                    </div>
                </div>

                <div class="inputtext">
                    Years Contributing
                    <div class="input-group">
                        <span class="input-group-addon">+</span>
                        <input type="number" id="yearscontributing" class="form-control" placeholder="0">
                    </div>
                </div>

                <div class="">
                    <input class="btn btn-default" type="submit" id="calculate" value="Calculate">
                </div>

                <div class="">
                    <input class="btn btn-default" type="submit" id="reset" value="Reset">
                </div>

                <div class="inputtext">
                    Ending Balance
                    <div class="input-group">
                        <span class="input-group-addon">$</span>
                        <input type="text" id="endingbalance" class="form-control" placeholder="0" readonly>
                    </div>
                </div>
            </div>

            <!-- Investing Chart -->

            <div class="col-sm-9 col-md-10">
                    <canvas id="canvas"></canvas>
            </div>

        </div>
    </div>
```

Comment: Please add the code to your question, too. From the Help Center: If it is possible to create a live example of the problem that you can link to (for example, on sqlfiddle.com or jsbin.com) then do so - but also include the code in your question itself. Not everyone can access external sites, and the links may break over time.

Comment: Will do. Just solved it with your advice:                 <div class="col-sm-9 col-md-10">
                    <div>
                        <canvas id="canvas"></canvas>
                    </div>
                </div>

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The problem stems from the fact that ChartJS doesn't take into account that the display-box on your elements is border-box. It is sizing the chart to the full width of the div without taking into account the padding.

In order to fix it, just put a div without any bootstrap column classes inside your column and target that with ChartJS.

Comment: Solved as you stated by putting a div wrapper in my column:                 <div class="col-sm-9 col-md-10">
                    <div>
                        <canvas id="canvas"></canvas>
                    </div>
                </div>